# Flicker free AWT application

Tags: java, animation, awt

I'm trying to write a silly little app using Java and AWT.

It simply runs and animates some shapes, so as a first step, I created a simple app that clears a canvas with `fillRect` every 50ms.

The problem is, my app flickers every now and then with the underlying window colour. Google is failing me when it comes to finding simple hello-world type examples of flicker-free animating AWT apps.

What would the skeletal code for something like this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look for double buffering code.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/javadoublebuffer.aspx